# Good .NET MVC Framework for Creating PDF Reports including Crosstab Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm looking for a good framework for creating nice looking reports in .NET ( MVC )  . I am leaning AWAY from Crystal , Dev Express and Telerik / Kendo - There is so much "stuff" in those frameworks and I'm sick of things breaking.

I need to do crosstab reports.  I am using SQL Server Express 2012 - can I do this sort of thing with Microsoft reporting services .. or is that quite basic?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Not a valid SO question.

Comment: - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.  I wasted my time coming here to see you write that? Find something better to do.. you obviously heve too much time on your hands.

Comment: No, I don't have too much time on my hands. This type of question is not allowed on SO. Please read the guidelines before asking questions. Also, be respectful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use SSRS, and crosstab reports are definitely possible. There is a WEB API you can use to deploy new reports, as well as render existing reports with parameters. If you report takes parameters, you can craft the proper HTTP query to link directly to it from your current MVC page.